# Can I access Amazon EBS storage from OpenShift gears?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openshift

I'm currently trying to design a web based system where there is already several Tb of data stored on an Amazon EBS instance. In an ideal world I'd like to deploy my applications on OpenShift so that it can autoscale with demand etc. The data is question is NetCDF files (and other large rasters) so a database is inappropriate for the storage.

What I'm unable to find out is can I access the existing storage from OpenShift or do I need to copy it all to new OpenShift allocated storage? and is a single filesystem going to be accessible from all the gears as it auto scales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do. You would need to move the data to S3 to access it. Sorry for the bad news

Comment: Or am i missing something?

Comment: Ohhh, Helps if I actually read the data type. Let me get back to you